# C# unit test pass on debug mode but fail on run mode

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'm coding in .net 4.5, visual studio 2019 on windows, testing with msUnitTests.

I'm testing a program that recieved a msg via tcp, does some manipulation on it, and then sends  back the recieved message (as is) to the sending app (currently - the test).

My test passes when running in debug mode, but failes on run mode.
I read some similar questions here in Stack Overflow, but none of them seemed to help me.
I tried adding Thread.sleep in my program before sending back the message, and in the test in several states, but none of them solved the problem.

I tried to create a sample of myProgram, but didn't manage to reproduce the bug, so I'm attaching my test code, and will be very thenkfull to someone that can help me figure out what can be the problem, and how to fix it.

`
namespace MyTests
{
[TestClass]
public class DataFlowSanitiyTest
{

```
    public DataFlowSanitiyTest()
    {
        MyProgram.Instance.Init();
        MyProgram.Instance.StartCommunication();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SanityTest()
    {
        // arrange
        byte[] expected = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Sanity Test");
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 4000);
       NetworkStream nws = client.GetStream();
        nws.ReadTimeout = 5000;

        // act

        nws.Write(expected, 0, expected.Length);
        byte[] actual = new byte[expected.Length];
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = nws.Read(actual, 0, actual.Length);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Reached timeout {0} ms, no message was recieved from MyProgram", nws.ReadTimeout);
        }

        //assert
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual, string.Format("Msg sent: {0}, Msg recieved: {1}",
            Encoding.Default.GetString(expected), Encoding.Default.GetString(actual)));
    }
}
```

}
`

When running in run mode - the test failed with the following message:                 Assert.Fail("Reached timeout {0} ms, no message was recieved from MyProgram", nws.ReadTimeout);

I'm so confused! Is there anyone that can help?